# How do we get (on Remix) the bytecode of a smart contract that has to make use of libraries?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix, erc20, openzeppelin

I am using Remix for compiling a simple ERC20 smart contract, and I would love to make use of libraries such as SafeMath. Do you know how to get the bytecode for a contract like this https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol ? Do you know how to make Remix compile a smart contract that is making use of libraries? Thank you so much for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1):

With remix you can import directly from a github link, so you can just include this in your imports:

`import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";`